# How to create a function that returns the number of nodes in a tree on a given level

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I tried this but it doesn't work.
As constraints, I can't use predefined functions, only cond, eql and mapcar . I can't use also ifs or variables or loops

```
(defun countNodes (level tree)
  (cond
    ((null tree) 0)
    ((eql level 0) 1)
    (t (apply #'+ (mapcar (lambda (level subtree) (countNodes (1- level) subtree)) tree)))
)
)
```

`(write (count-nodes-on-level   '(1 (2 (3 (6 7) 4) 5))  4))`

This is the given error: *** - MAPCAR: A proper list must not end with1

I tried to look on stackoverflow for some answer but I didn't find anything that could help me

EDIT
 `(write   (count-nodes '(a (b (c)) (d) (e (f)))  1))` will return 1

this is an example that i found and sorry for my mistake but I got wrong the definition of the supposed tree.It looks like the root is 'a' and it has 3 child, 'b' 'd' and 'e', 'c' is child of 'b' and 'f' is child of e

Comment: Can you have a little bit different structure of the tree or is `'(1 (2 (3 (6 7) 4) 5))` part of the assignment and you can't change it?

Comment: Prefer `(reduce #'+ ...)` to `(apply #'+ ...)` in Common Lisp. `apply` may run into an argument passing limit.

Comment: You're not testing for the `atom` case. You rmain `cond` tests whether the tree is `null` or not; if it is not `null` it assumes that it is a list that can be traversed with `mapcar`. That's why you run into the problem.   I think you need to handle the `atom` case and the list case, and in both of those, you have to divide into subcases: this is the level we are looking for or not.  If a list occurs on the expected level, we have to count its length. If an atom occurs at the expected level, we return 1 (as you have).

Comment: @MartinPůda basically that is a tree that have 1 as the root, 2 child nodes that are 2 and  5, 2 has another 2 childs, 3 and 4 and 3 has 6 and 7 as childs

Comment: You must explain what definition of tree you are using. It seems from your comments that, under your working definition, the list `(a b c)` isn't a tree with three atoms, but actually a node whose label is `a`, which has two children `b` and `c`. If so, we must implement the recursion and all the rest of the processing such that the first element, the label, is ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example, without a precise definition of tree, I suppose that a tree is either an atom (meaning that it is a tree with root the atom, and without children), or a list, possibly empty, of which the car is the root, and the cdr is the list of the children.

With this hypothesis, here is a version of the function that can solve your problem:

```
(defun countNodes (level tree)
  (cond ((null tree) 0)
        ((eql level 0) 1)
        ((atom tree) 0)
        (t (apply #'+ (mapcar 
                       (lambda (subtree) (countNodes (1- level) subtree))
                       (cdr tree))))))
```

Comment: I'm not sure if your code implements the correct requirements. You're assuming that when the level is the expected level, it's OK to return 1.  But what if `tree` happens to be `(1 2 (3 4) 5)`? In that case we should probably return 4, the length of the list.

Comment: The tree definition I use here is that a tree is a list of sublists, which each sublist containing some atoms, like (1((2) (3))) is a tree with root 1 and childs 2 and 3, (1 (2 (3 (4)))) is a tree with root 1 a child 2, 3 is child of 2 and 4 is child of 3. My given example is this: 
(countNodes 1 (a (b (c)) (d) (e (f))) ) should return 3. I may not understand completely what i was supposed to do

Comment: At level zero, the list has 4 elements: `a`, `(b (c))`, `(d)`, `(e (f))` which is its length, and that should arguably be the level zero count. At level 1, we add up the lengths of those items that are sulists, so again 4: `(b (c))` is length 2, `(d)` is 1, `(e (f))` 2.  `a` is not counted any more; it bottomed out at level 0,

Comment: @Kaz, I added a clarification to the hypothesis. As I said, in the question there is not a clear definition of tree, so my definition is just a guess.

Comment: There is the possible interpretation of "tree" as a binary tree of car/cdr. So that every time we traverse `car` or `cdr`, the level deepens. I don't think that's the interpretation intended here; tree means n-ary tree represented as a nested list. So it's clear that in, say ((x) (x x x) ((y y) x) ((y (z z) y) x), the x's are all on the same level, and so are the y's and z's; that the y's are one level deeper  than x's and that in ((y y) x), the (y y) and x node are on the same level.

Comment: But it looks as if the tree may in fact be labeled syntax, as in `(a b c)` means "node named `a` with two children `b` and `c`".

Answer (score 1):

I would adopt the following requirements and write it like this:

```
(defun count-nodes (tree level)
  (cond
    ((atom tree) 0)
    ((plusp level) (reduce #'+ (mapcar (lambda (subtree)
                                         (count-nodes subtree (1- level)))
                                        tree)))
    (t (length tree))))
```

Note that we never return 1 for the `atom` case; for both the empty subtree and an atom like 42, we just return 0. This works because `length` counts the atoms for us already; if we return 1, we get a double count.

Some tests:

```
[1]> (count-nodes '(1 2 3 (4)) 0)
4
[2]> (count-nodes '(1 2 3 (4)) 1)
1
[3]> (count-nodes '(1 2 3 (4)) 2)
0
[4]> (count-nodes '(1 2 3 (4)) 3)
0
```

As you can see, at level 0 we just return the `length`, which is 4. At level 1, the length of `(4)` gets reported. Then after that zero.

```
[5]> (count-nodes '(1 2 3 (4) (5) (6 7 8)) 1)
5
```

Here, the lengths of `(4)` `(5)` and `(6 7 8)` get added together, yielding 5.

If `reduce` and `length` are not on the list of allowed functions, you can write them yourself. `length` can be made out of `mapcar` along these lines:

```
(defun len (list)
  (let ((count 0))
    (mapcar (lambda (item) (inc count)) list)
    count))
```

**EDIT:** Now, it turns out that the definition of "tree" for the purposes of the problem is a labeled abstraction. That is to say, the list `(1 2 3)` is being given a meaning that the first element is a label, and only the se cond and subsequent elements are the children. A label is not a subtree and thus not recursed into or counted. The quick fix to make the code ignore labels is this:

```
(defun count-nodes (tree level)
  (cond
    ((atom tree) 0)
    ((plusp level) (reduce #'+ (mapcar (lambda (subtree)
                                         (count-nodes subtree (1- level)))
                                        (cdr tree)))) ;; cdr here
    (t (length (cdr tree))))) ;; cdr here
```

Examples:

```
[2]> (count-nodes '(a b c) 0)
2
[3]> (count-nodes '(a b c) 1)
0
[4]> (count-nodes '(a (b) c) 1)
0
[5]> (count-nodes '(a (b 1) c) 1)
1
[6]> (count-nodes '(a (b 1) (c 1)) 1)
2
[7]> (count-nodes '(a (b 1) (c 1 (d 2 3))) 1)
3
[8]> (count-nodes '(a (b 1) (c 1 (d 2 3))) 2)
2
```

We now need to answer the requirements question: is `()`/`nil` actually a valid tree? Is `(a 1 ())` a valid tree node with label `a` and two children `1` and `nil`, or is `()` an invalid node lacking a label? With the quick fix to the code above, we take the former view: `()` is just another atom. We tolerate it silently and count it.

Comment: Can you look please at my edit, this function for the given example with characters will return 5 which is wrong